# JBOD enclosure/chassis that holds more than five (5) HDDs with only one eSATA Port?

Tags: dvr

I have a DVR Security System with one eSATA port. It is connected to a 5 disk RAID tower via eSATA. I need more storage!

- [DVR VANGUARD II 16x8H](https://www.everfocus.com/product/ins.php?index_id=792)
- [RAID enclosure SY-ENC50122](https://www.sybausa.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=1068)

I've been running RAID tower with the RAID switches turned OFF. Not sure if this is RAID NORMAL or JBOD. Either way, it has been working for a couple of years fantastically. The DVR has a storage capacity of 8TB per disk max, so higher capacity disks aren't an option.

I am trying to find some kind of enclosure/chassis that will hold more than 5 disks and will communicate through one single eSATA port. This DVR does NOT allow me to install RAID software. It just sees individual disks and gives me an option to format and record, nothing else is possible.

Anyone got any ideas? Know of any daisy chain enclosures? SAS? I do have the two internal SATAs occupied. Looking for about 8-10 external disks, preferably 3.5".

Am I overlooking something obvious? Is there such a creature as an external eSATA multiplier?

Comment: Whatever your enclosure is doing, it's probably not JBOD; eSATA only supports presenting as one disk, unless you use port multiplication, which is generally not well supported. I don't think your current setup is very scalable, if nothing else due to drive reliability; you'll almost certainly want to set up a separate NAS and either configure FTP upload, or use a different NVR.

Comment: SATA is designed to do 1 port to 1 drive, so any enclosure with eSATA on it is going to virtualize all of its storage as one drive, or possibly just expose one of the drives at all. You'd have to consult the manual for your existing box to know what the RAID switches mean in the current position, it probably is making them work like JBOD but the eSATA port pretends to be one big drive.

Answer (score 0):

https://mediasonicstore.com/products/mediasonic-8-bay-hard-drive-enclosure-usb-3-0-esata-h82-su3s2

Mediasonic 8 Bay Hard Drive Enclosure - USB 3.0 & eSATA (H82-SU3S3)